# client connect/disconnect events in qjsonrpc

Tags: c++, json, qt, json-rpc

Forgive me my bad English. 
I just started using `qjsonrpc`, and I like this thing. 
But recently I encountered a problem when using QJsonRpcTcpServer in my application: how can I keep track of a client connect/disconnect?

Comment: This could pretty easily be added to the library (clientConnected()/clientDisconnected()) signals in QJsonRpcAbstractServer, etc). Patches are welcome (hopefully with a test or two :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to pass a `QJsonRpcTcpServerPrivate` instance to the `QJsonRpcTcpServer::QJsonRpcTcpServer` ctor, so I'd just subclass `QJsonRpcTcpServerPrivate` and override the following methods:

- `void QJsonRpcTcpServerPrivate::_q_processIncomingConnection()`
- `void QJsonRpcTcpServerPrivate::_q_clientDisconnected()`

[github://devonit/qjsonrpc/src/qjsonrpctcpserver.cpp](https://bitbucket.org/devonit/qjsonrpc/src/6b31483df936b4a2380320e2ad86d0440fba151c/src/qjsonrpctcpserver.cpp?at=master)

You could then do something like casting the `tcpSocket*` to an appropriately long integer type and use that as the key to some dictionary/map.